# Bootstrap scaffolding limitations

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scaffolding

I am trying to use bootstrap scaffold for first time and wonder if I can do that. 
`<header class="row"></header> // this covers browsers width
    <div id="main-container" style="maring:auto; max-width:1200px"> I want this to be centered and not  more   than 1200px
    <div class="row" class="span12" id="main">
    </div>
    </div>`
The idea is that I want to use the scaffolding feature in different areas inside my html document independently, can I do it or I am forced to go on a whole page perspective ?

Answer (score 0):

Well.. the first thing you're going to want is to start with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You do not have to do the entire page, you only put it around whatever you want.

```
<!-- The container is necessary for your rows -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Each row will hold a row of 'spans' -->
    <div class="row">
        <!-- This will center whatever content you want. -->
        <div class="offset2 span8">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```